# Почему не происходит схлопывание margin?

Tags: html, css, margin

У меня есть родитель, внутри которого расположен дочерний элемент. Можно увидеть, что схлопывание марджинов происходит только сверху родительского элемента.
Например:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellowgreen;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

"Внизу" родительского элемента этого схлопывания не происходит.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellowgreen;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Нижний отступ дочернего элемента игнорируется. Хотя по идее должно быть так:

> Margin самого контейнера и margin первого блока накладываются, и в итоге место перед контейнером равно наибольшему из них. Тоже самое происходит и внизу с нижними margin'ами контейнера и последнего вложенного блока.

Проблема в том, что в последнем примере элемент не является последним? Вот:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: yellowgreen;
}

.child_2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: purple;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child_2"></div>
</div>
```

Результат тот же... Чего именно я не понимаю?

Comment: Что-то я ничего не понял. margin-bottom у контейнера 0px, margin-bottom у вложенного блока 80px, накладываем и выбираем больший маргин, получаем 80px — именно такой маргин снизу я и вижу, всё правильно, ничего не игнорируется. Не могли бы вы пояснить, что именно не так в двух последних примерах?

Comment: @andreymal и правда, немного размазано описан вопрос. Дело в том, что нижний марджин виден, но тем не менее он не работает. Вот как пример: [работа марджина дочернего элемента](https://jsfiddle.net/7ya2mh1r/) и [работа марджина родительского элемента.](https://jsfiddle.net/7ya2mh1r/1/) Во втором примере нормальный работающий марджин, а в первом нет.

Comment: @Eva, стоит перенести примеры из jsfiddle в сам вопрос, потому что в текущих примерах - не видно, что работает не так.

Comment: проблема в том что .parent height задан жестко 300px вот и идуший за ней div block прижимается как только эти 300px заканчиваются надо родителю задать margin-bottom: 80px; наверное есть другие варианты я знаю этот